# Flatten contingency table in R

Tags: r

I have a contingency table, eg the built in Titanic dataset, and I want a way to drop a variable and merge all the values together. Sort of project the data down onto the lower dimensional space.

e.g. Just looking at one 2-d slice of the table

```
      Sex
Class  Male Female
  1st    57    140
  2nd    14     80
  3rd    75     76
  Crew  192     20
```

If we were to drop the Sex variable, I would want to end up with a 1-d contingency table that looked like:

```
Class  Freq
  1st   197
  2nd    94
  3rd   151
  Crew  212
```

My actual use case is an N dimensional table that I want to be able to construct all N 1-way and N*(N-1)/2 2-way tables from. It feels like there should be a simple way to get this to work.

EDIT: Note that this is not a duplicate of the question this has been linked with, as that is referring to *data tables*, not *contingency tables*. The solution here is to convert the *contingency table* to a *data table*, then use xtabs to get back to a *contingency table*. The referenced solution only deals with the case of starting with a data table and wanting to end up with a data table.

Comment: you should provide sample data or specify which built-in Titanic dataset you are using.  (There's one in `datasets`, another in `rpart.plot` that is similar to the Kaggle one)

Comment: As I said, the example I was using was the built in Titanic {datasets}. The one you get by just typing Titanic. I can't even find the rpart.plot version. Is that a contingency table? Either way, the content of the data doesn't matter, just how to manipulate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data(Titanic)
library(dplyr)

as.data.frame(Titanic) %>% group_by(Class) %>% summarise(n=sum(Freq))

# Class     n
# (fctr) (dbl)
# 1    1st   325
# 2    2nd   285
# 3    3rd   706
# 4   Crew   885
```

or data.table:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(Titanic)[, .(n = sum(N)), keyby=Class]
```

you can make a vector of dim names and then loop over `get(dimname)` in dplyr or data.table to do 1-way or 2-way freqs.

example:

```
dims <- c('Class','Sex','Age')
dt <- as.data.table(Titanic)
for(dim in dims)
  print(dt[, .(n = sum(N)), keyby = get(dim)])
```

Note that `get` is one way of passing a variable name to do the frequency tables programmatically.

To do a 2-way table in `data.table`, you can use `dcast`:

```
dcast.data.table(dt, Age ~ Class, value.var='N', fun.aggregate=sum)
#      Age 1st 2nd 3rd Crew
# 1: Adult 319 261 627  885
# 2: Child   6  24  79    0
```

To produce multiple 2-way tables with `dcast` you would need to build the formula programatically, e.g.  `formula = as.formula(paste(v1,v2,sep='~'))`

Since data.table syntax takes some getting used to, if you want to stay inside the 'tidyverse' for 2-way tables you can just do:

```
data(Titanic)
library('dplyr')
library('tidyr')

as.data.frame(Titanic) %>% 
  group_by(Age,Class) %>% 
  summarise(n=sum(Freq)) %>%
  spread(Class, n)

#      Age   1st   2nd   3rd  Crew
#   (fctr) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
# 1  Child     6    24    79     0
# 2  Adult   319   261   627   885
```

Comment: This is excellent, thank you. I tries using the data.table version, and that allows you to do exactly what I want. It seems you don't even need the get() in the keyby argument, it will work with a string name. For example:
`as.data.table(Titanic)[, (n = sum(N)), keyby = c("Class", "Age")]`
and the order in which the elements of keyby are specified will determine the order the columns are created in the output.

Comment: Even though this solution is incomplete, I had marked this as the answer, assuming I could suggest remaining portion as an edit. As you have rejected the edit, leaving this answer incomplete, I have unmarked it as the answer.
So an example including the complete transformation back to a contingency table again,
`myData = as.data.table(Titanic)[, (n = sum(N)), keyby = c("Age", "Class")]`

`myContingencyTable = xtabs(as.formula("V1 ~ Age + Class"), data = myData)`
and myTable is now a contingency table containing only the variables specified.

Comment: @user2711915 please see edit -- using `xtabs` is an unnecessary step if you are already using `as.data.table`

Comment: Ok, that completes the solution, thank you. I'm slightly confused by the fact that the formula for dcast is `Age ~ Class`, while for xtabs it is `V1 ~ Age + Class`, but either is simple to build programatically.